# Spring batch: conditional execution of steps

Tags: java, spring, properties, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Batch job which contains several steps (more than 10).

I have a properties file which indicates if one step should be executed or not.

For instance, in my properties file :
EXECUTE_STEP1=0
EXECUTE_STEP2=1

indicates that step2 should be executed and step1 should not.

How can I translate this in my Spring Batch configuration? Is it possible?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: You likely have to implement JobExecutionDecider with an implementation that evaluates your configuration. Then it would be placed inbetween steps, evaluating whether the next step should run or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did:
- once my properties are set, I put all the step names which has to be executed in a Stack,
- I have created a Decider which pops the Stack, and decides which step has to be executed by returning a new FlowExecutionStatus.

Hejk